# how can I separate the C:\ drive from all drivers?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, drives

I have this program but I have an issue when this try to access the FIRST if... I need to separate the drivers and only get the total size of C:\. When the program stops at the if... say that the drive is not ready. What can I do?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string mainHD = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System));

        GetTotalFreeSpace(mainHD);

        DriveInfo[] drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives();
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
        {
            if (drive.VolumeLabel != @"C:\")
            {
                //There are more attributes you can use.
                //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
                string drivesname = drive.Name;
                Console.WriteLine(drivesname);
                if (drive.IsReady) Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
            }
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if (drive.IsReady && drive.Name == driveName)
            {
                return drive.TotalSize;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you should be testing `drive.IsReady` before checking `drive.VolumeLabel`.

Take a look at the [MSDN sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Try this:

```
foreach (DriveInfo drive in drives)
{
    if (drive.IsReady && drive.VolumeLabel != @"C:\")
    {
        //There are more attributes you can use.
        //Check the MSDN link for a complete example.
        string drivesname = drive.Name;
        Console.WriteLine(drivesname);
        Console.WriteLine(drive.TotalSize);
    }
}
```

While this may be an issue of the C: drive not being ready, it could also be a case where there is an A: or B: floppy drive, and in that case, continuing to check `IsReady` until it is ready is probably not a good idea.

Comment: Thank You so much, you resolve my problem... it works in the first try!!

Comment: Glad to help. Good luck with the rest of your program.

Answer (score 1):

The question is unclear.  Going by the code, this is one of those rare cases where spin/wait may be the best option.  There are two calls to `Drive.IsReady` which can both benefit from spin/wait.  The latter could be done like...

```
private static long GetTotalFreeSpace(string driveName)
    {
        foreach (DriveInfo drive in DriveInfo.GetDrives())
        {
            if(!Drive.IsReady)
                //spin wait implemented however you deem appropriate.  Maybe sleep a second or so
            if (drive.Name == driveName)
            {
                return drive.TotalSize;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Second, according to MSDN:

> IsReady indicates whether a drive is ready. For example, it indicates
>   whether a CD is in a CD drive or whether a removable storage device is
>   ready for read/write operations. If you do not test whether a drive is
>   ready, and it is not ready, querying the drive using DriveInfo will
>   raise an IOException.

I recommend you add some logic to handle `IOException` as well.

Answer (score 0):

I seem to remember this being a problem of trying to access the 'A:' drive that has no disk in it.  Even if you don't actually have a drive at A:, a lot of machines will report it there anyway.

Comment: Does this answer the question?